# crop image cancel

Tags: android

```
        case CROP_FROM_CAMERA:          
                        if(mImageCaptureUri!=null){
                        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

                        if (extras != null) {               
                            Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");
                            bmp = photo;
                         }
 builder.setOnCancelListener( new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel( DialogInterface dialog ) {

                        if (mImageCaptureUri != null ) {
                            getContentResolver().delete(mImageCaptureUri, null, null );
                            mImageCaptureUri = null;
                        }
                    }
                } );
```

When I am trying cancell cropped image I receive null pointer exception in Bundle extras=data.getExtras(); What should I do here to avoid this problem. Is there any solution here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also get a result code which tells you if it went okay:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == CROP_FROM_CAMERA){

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
           // do stuff when you've got a result
        } else{ /* canceled code here */ }
```

Tada! :D